# How are research study results on marketing psychology generally interpreted?

Tags: markets, uncertainty, research

I'm getting into marketing. I've been reading books, articles and even research papers on the topic. I'm confused about how to actually interpret information and research study results in this field.

In math research, statements are either true or false, but marketing research seems more nuanced and context-dependent.

For example, if I come across a book or article suggesting that customer promise-based branding is superior to traditional branding, and it's backed by research studies, how can I determine if this information is reliable?

At the end of the day, even if a marketing strategy has worked throughout the years for many products, and it has been studied in psychology why it works, then there's still a chance that another marketing strategy might work better, right?